# How to get SKSpriteNode name?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working with this code I've found and trying to figure out how to get the node names for my objects?

Here's part of the code:

```
let sprite1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
let sprite3 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
let sprite4 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

var selected: [UITouch: SKNode] = [:]

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    selected = [:]
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        selected[touch as UITouch] = nodeAtPoint(location)

        println(self.name)
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the `println` to return the `SKSprintNode` name (sprite1, sprite2, sprite3 or sprite4)... I've tried several things, bit all I get is `´nil´`.

Is this possible?

**Added:**

So, to follow up, how can I detect whether the touch is within my objects? Here's some more code:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        for (touch, node) in selected{
            if !contains(SKScene, node){
                let action = SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: 0.1)
                node.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(action, count: 1))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

With the `if !contains(SKScene, node)` (which is not working, can't test on `SKScene`) I want to detect if the touch was on the object or outside.. If outside (touch is SKScene) I don't want to do anything..

The reason I want to do it this way and not test on `let` names as i.e `sprite1` is that I'm planning to make all `SKSpriteNode` programmatically, so I don't necessary know the name of the node-object..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, getting closer :-D Found out how to fix the if statement: `if !contains([self], node)`... That works! But is it the right way of doing thing?

Comment: Also moved the code under `touchesEnded` to `touchesMoved` , so now are the boxes (objects) following the touch on the screen smoothly :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the name of the variable, but you are not setting the name of the SKSpriteNode.  It should be:

```
 sprite1.name = @"sprite1";
```

Follow suit for the rest of your sprites.

Another thing I noticed is that you call self.name.  I am pretty sure self refers to the scene, if that is where this code is located.  Instead, you should save the selected as an SKSpriteNode and call selected.name.

Comment: Ok, I see... The `self.name` was just one of many tings I tried ;-) What I'm trying to acheive here is to understand how I can detect which node I'm touching.. The code is woriking, but I can't really understand why :-o

Comment: Ok.  So when you touch something, you are pointing Selected at the touched node (if any).  Then, you are returning the name of the node that Selected name is pointing at.  This gives you access to your SKSpriteNodes just by touching one.  If you want to execute code when particular nodes are touched, you need to check if the Selected node.name is equal to the node you are checking if it touched.  If so, run some code.  This would take place right after you set the selected node.

Comment: Yupp, as for the other post you answered; had do write it like this: `sprite1.name = "sprite1"`