# Why can not set name of SKSprite in its init function?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, initialization, skspritenode

I have extended SKSpriteNode and want set its name attribute in its init function:

```
class Ship: SKSpriteNode {


    var id: Int

    /**
     *  Image name of sprite image for this bubble.
     **/
    var image: String

    //some other vars but NOT name, because its super class SKNode has already name

    init(ship: (name: String, <other vars>), position: CGPoint) {

        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: self.image)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        self.name = name //here I set its name!!!
        self.position = position

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width / 2)
        self.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

But later, when I create a 'Ship' with (ship[1] are some values including name):

```
var titanic = Ship(ship: ship[1], position: shipPosition!)
println(titanic.name) //nil
self.addChild(titanic)
titanic.name = 'titanic'
println(titanic.name) //titanic
```

As you can see - name is not set on initialization - I have to set it after it is created.

**How can I set this name in its init method? Or will I have to name it only after its creation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, `self.name = name` actually means the same thing as `self.name = self.name`.

You are trying to pass the variable in a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329), so you probably want `self.name = ship.name`. (Or even `name = ship.name`.)

Or, you could pass these all as arguments directly to the initializer:

```
init(named name: String, <other vars>, position: CGPoint) {
    // ...
    self.name = name
}

Ship(named: "titanic", <other vars>, position: shipPosition!)
```

Comment: I do this `self.name = name` in the initializer and it did not work.

Comment: If you didn't make the change I suggested, then you need to use `self.name = ship.name`.

Comment: Ahhh! I got it - my mistake - just missed out to use the tuple I use for init this class. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this : [How to get SKSpriteNode name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281640/how-to-get-skspritenode-name) ?

Try

```
sprite1.name = @"sprite1";
```

And as @jtbandes noted, it is probably easier to initialize the name directly.